# How can I pass a variable as an argument to the buffer command in Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer

I want to do something like:

```
let b = bufnr('%')
" do something that adds (potentially loads of) new buffers
buffer b
```

But I get the error

```
"No matching buffer for b"
```

How can "expand" the variable b, or work around this in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
:exe "buffer ".b
```

For more information:

```
:h :exe
```

Comment: Nice. So there isn't a way to "expand" variables per-se?

Comment: There is {} that can be used when building the name of other variables -> After `let g:bar = '1'`, `g:foo_{bar}` designs the variable `g:foo1`. `:h curly-braces-names`. It doesn't always work in all contexts -- but I must admit I don't remember which context are incompatible with this syntax. OTOH `:exe` will always work.